# How can I import `.ics` data (from Outlook) to org mode

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I want to import `.ics` files (from Outlook) to my `org-agenda`. How can I do that? I could find only exporting options.

Comment: Try a search for 'ical2org'. Lots of hits, each written in a different language (Elisp, Ruby, Python, Go, Awk...).